# asp.net drop down firing wrong event

Tags: asp.net, events, drop-down-menu

I'm using VS 2010, .net 4, vb.net.  I have an asp.net site and on a page have 2 drop down lists.

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClassIndex" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClassQBankList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

When the page first loads i can click on either of these, select an item and the event fires correctly.  When i select either of the drop down boxes as a second operation, the first drop down, `ddlClassIndex.SelectedIndexChanged` fires.   What have i done wrong that this would be happening.  I do a `page.ispostback=false` check when the page loads and we are also using master pages.

Any idea?

sure..

```
 Private Sub LoadClass()
    Dim Os As List(Of Dempsey.OldeTestClassIndex) = Nothing
    Dim Oc As New Dempsey.OldeTestClassIndex_Controller
    Os = Oc._GetClassIndexData(0)

    Dim X = From w In Os
            Where w.Active = 3
            Select w

    Os = X.ToList

    With Me.ddlClassIndex
        .DataSource = Os.OrderBy(Function(o) o.ClassTitle)
        .DataTextField = "ClassTitle"
        .DataValueField = "tblClassIndexID"
        .DataBind()
        .Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Choose Class Title", "0"))
        .SelectedIndex = 0
    End With


End Sub



Protected Sub ddlClassIndex_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlClassIndex.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Me.ddlClassIndex.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        If ClassHasCategories(Me.ddlClassIndex) = True Then
            Response.Redirect("AddEditQBank.aspx?ClassIndexID=" & Me.ddlClassIndex.SelectedItem.Value)
        Else
            Me.lblStatus.Text = "No Categories"
            Me.lblStatus.Visible = True
        End If

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LoadClassQBankList()
    Dim ary As New ArrayList
    ary.Add(1)
    ary.Add(2)
    ary.Add(3)

    Dim Os As List(Of Dempsey.OldeTestClassIndex) = Nothing
    Dim Oc As New Dempsey.OldeTestClassIndex_Controller
    Os = Oc._GetClassIndexData(0)

    Dim X = From w In Os Join l In ary On w.Active Equals l
            Where w.KT = 1 And w.RandomTest = 1
                    Select w

    Os = X.ToList

    With Me.ddlClassQBankList
        .DataSource = Os.OrderBy(Function(o) o.ClassTitle)
        .DataTextField = "ClassTitle"
        .DataValueField = "tblClassIndexID"
        .DataBind()
        .Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Choose Class Title", "0"))
        .SelectedIndex = 0
    End With

End Sub
Protected Sub ddlClassQBankList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlClassQBankList.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Me.ddlClassQBankList.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        Response.Redirect("ClassQBankList.aspx" & "?ClassIndexID=" & Me.ddlClassQBankList.SelectedValue)
    End If
End Sub
```

~~~~~~~~~~
More info
I am checking for page postback. When i select from the drop down, it redirects to a different page. When i click the back button and selected another value in the other drop down, both SelectedIndexChanged fire. So i do i need to do something with viewstate? before i redired to the other page?

Comment: Can you include the code which wires up the events to the dropdowns.

Comment: What do you mean with *I do a page.ispostback=false check when the page loads*?
What are you doing when `not Page.IsPostBack`? You should only bind the datasource to them when `not Page.IsPostBack`. Are the Dropdowns cascading? What i mean is, does it affect the selectedindex of the other Dropdown when one is selected? What are you doing in the SelectedIndexChangedEvent of both? Ok, these are more questions than answers, but maybe it helps you to get on the right track.

Comment: It just occurred to me that he's probably using VB.Net using the 'Handles' to wire the events, and most likely copy pasted the method and renamed the method, forgetting the change the control it handles.

Comment: That might be the reason. I forgot that more than once myself. But that would not explain why the first dropdown's selectedindexchanged event occurs when the second was selected. He mentions that the correct handler of the second ddl is called on first time but not on second.

Comment: He needs to show us how hes wiring the events up.

Comment: i've added the code... hopefully that will help

Comment: when are you calling `LoadClass` and `LoadClassQBankList`? Is it surrounded by an `If Not IsPostBack`? You are not redirecting to this page in one of the dropdown-handlers, aren't you?

Comment: yes.. it is wrapped in a if not ispostback... i've figured out more of the problem.. just no solution.  when i select from the drop down, it redirects to a different page.  When i click the back button and selected another value in the other drop down, both SelectedIndexChanged fire.  So i do i need to do something with viewstate? before i redired to the other page?

Answer (score 0):

Super old, but for the poor souls still seeing this lacklustre answer you might find some relief in Rick Strahl's (equally old) post: [West Wind: ASP.NET ListBoxes, SelectedValue and ViewState](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Mar/18/ASPNET-ListBoxes-SelectedValue-and-ViewState).

Spoiler alert: it's a bit hacky and involves doing some of your own view state management.